# MUI File Input (Accept Only Image)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, javascript-objects

I have a file input using [MUI File Input](https://viclafouch.github.io/mui-file-input/) react. I have a code that works fine. However, how can I restrict this file input that accepts only images?

These are my work so far:

```
const [locationImg, setLocationImg] = useState(null)

  const handleLocationImgChange = locationImg => {
    setLocationImg(locationImg)
  }

return(
 <MuiFileInput value={locationImg} onChange={handleLocationImgChange} multiple size='small' fullWidth />
)
```

Comment: Have you tried using the [accept](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/accept) property, like it would be for normal HTML? I don't know, if that property is included, but might be worth a try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in [their docs](https://viclafouch.github.io/mui-file-input/docs/inheritance/), [MUI TextField](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/text-field/)'s props can also be used.

```jsx
<MuiFileInput
  inputProps={{ accept: "image/png, image/gif, image/jpeg" }}
  value={locationImg}
  onChange={handleLocationImgChange}
  multiple
  size="small"
  fullWidth
/>;
```

Comment: That works for me. You save my day. Cheeerrss!